# AS3 2D array initialization

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

What is wrong with this **Array Initialization**
I am getting syntax errors
This class hold levels.
I cant figure out why its not working.
Previously i used to intialize 2d arrays by first declaring an array of certain length then assigning 
arrays to the elemnets of main array.But when i used this method i am not getting it right

```
package  {

public class Levels {

    public var Level1:Array = new Array();
    public var Level2:Array = new Array();
    public var Level3:Array = new Array();
    public var Level4:Array = new Array();
    public var Level5:Array = new Array();
    public var Level6:Array = new Array();

    public function Levels() {
        Level1[] =((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level2[] =((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level3[] = ((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level4[]= ((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level4[]= ((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level5[]= ((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
        Level6[]= ((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                   (0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1));
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Remove square brackets from assignment, and replace round brackets with square brackets on the right side of assignment. `Level1 = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],...];`

Comment: @Vesper only remoeing square brackets worked Level1 = ((1,1,..),(0,1,..))

Comment: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type Array.. I don't know what you are building with, but this does not work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like PHP or some that kind of language - Action Script Array has different approach. You can either use what @Vesper said:

```
Level1 = [ // array
    [1, 1, 0, 1], // first element, child array
    [0, 0, 0, 0], // second element, child array
    [0, 1, 1, 1]
];
```

Or you can use push:

```
Level1.push([0, 1, 0, 1]); // first element, child array
Level1.push([1, 1, 1, 1]); // second element, child array
```

And just to mention, if you want to use brackets to get/set element of the array, you **must** provide index:

```
Level1[0] = [0, 0, 0]; // set first element
Level1[1] = [1, 1, 1]; // set second element
trace(Level[2]); // throws error in your case as there is no such element
```

Comment: Removing the square brackets after array name worked